# Error creating step functions. Not authorized to assume the provided role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

I got error while creating step functions with terraform:

```
Error: Error creating Step Function State Machine: AccessDeniedException: Neither the global service principal states.amazonaws.com, nor the regional one is authorized to assume the provided role.
```

I tried add depends_on block in resource aws_sfn_state_machine, but it doesn't help.
But if I create role separately from a step function and then I set role_arn in resource aws_sfn_state_machine everything works. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you shared seems to be suggesting that the assume role policy for the given role does not include any of the service principals used by Step Functions. The role would need an assume role policy that lists this service as one of its allowed principals:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

In Terraform we'd usually set this as an argument of an `aws_iam_role` resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "stepfunctions"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

We can then refer to that role's ARN in a `aws_sfn_state_machine` resource, which will automatically create a dependency to ensure that Terraform will not try to create the step function until it has created the role:

```
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "example" {
  name     = "my-state-machine"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn

  # ...
}
```

Unfortunately due to the internal design of AWS IAM it can sometimes take a few minutes after creating an IAM object before that object becomes fully-functional. The AWS API does not expose any totally-reliable way to detect when an IAM principal is fully-functional after a settings change, so the Terraform AWS provider often makes a best effort to poll for the completion but cannot always guarantee that.

If you still see the error you mentioned with a configuration like the above, I'd suggest to wait 10 minutes after you see the error and try running `terraform apply` again (*without* destroying the role and recreating it) to see if it works. Of course, needing to run Terraform twice to get the desired answer is far from convenient, but at least identifying delayed consistency as the cause will avoid spending time investigating other possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

`Depends_on` is likely referencing that resource A should be created if resource B is also going to be created. It doesn't apply role to a state machine. `role_arn` is an explicit setting for state machine to use this particular role.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

below is the terraform role for step function hope this will help

#iam/state-assume-policy.json

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

#role.tf

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess"
}
data "aws_iam_policy" "CloudWatchLogsFullAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
}
data "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaRole" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "StepFunctionQuantumRole" {
  name               = "CompanyNameStepFunctionRole"
  assume_role_policy = file("iam/state-assume-policy.json")
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "step_function_attach_policy_awsstepfunctionfullaccess" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.StepFunctionQuantumRole.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess.arn
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "step_function_attach_policy_cloudwatchlogsfullaccess" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.StepFunctionQuantumRole.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.CloudWatchLogsFullAccess.arn
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "step_function_attach_policy_awslambdarole" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.StepFunctionQuantumRole.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.AWSLambdaRole.arn
}
```

#step-function.tf

```
// Create state machine for step function
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine" {
  name       = "nameofstatemachine"
  role_arn   = aws_iam_role.StepFunctionQuantumRole.arn
  defination = <<EOF add your defination EOF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by specifying region as well.

```
 {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "states.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
```